# SVN - How to restrict subfolders for some users in subversion

Tags: svn, subversive

I'm using SVN with authorization policies.

Here is my project directory :

```
-project
  -grails-app
    -domain
      -compte
      -contrat
      -parametrage
      -securityplugin
      -credoc
```

I want to grant to a specific user (user2), read/write to the /project/grails-app/domain/compte directory only.

I tried in my authz file

> ```
> [project:/project/grails-app/domain/compte]
> user2 = rw
> ```

it works great ! but the parent directories are forbidden.

**When I want to read the /project/grails-app/domain, I want to see only the 'compte' directory.**

Thank you so much.

Comment: You got expected from rule result. There are your troubles here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like things are working as designed. how are you serving svn? if you're serving over http you could rewrite the url, something like `http://server/repo/compte` to `http://server/repo/project/grails-app/domain/compte`  but that seems like a pain - I wouldn't bother.